# Can I run terminal commands such as SFTP/SSH through a mathematica notebook?

Tags: command-line

I'm generating an array using Mathematica which produces a single .dat file. I then use SFTP/SCP to transfer it to the staff Linux cluster.

This isn't a particularly difficult task but is there a way to execute the terminal command through a mathematica notebook as if it were the MacOS terminal?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`CopyFile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopyFile.html) with a [`RemoteFile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoteFile.html) parameter, including the necessary [`Authentication`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Authentication.html) options

```
CopyFile[
    "/tmp/yourlocalfile.dat",
    RemoteFile[
        "sftp://host.example.com/tmp/yourremotefile.dat",
        Authentication -> <|
            "Username" -> "user",
            "SSHKey" -> File["/path/.ssh/id_rsa"]
            |>
    ]
]
```

`CopyFile` it's very flexible and accepts also [`ExternalStorageObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalStorageObject.html) and [`CloudObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObject.html).

There are public test servers to play with "SCP"/"SFTP", this one is read-only, you can `CopyFile` from there to your local drive, for tests.

```
RemoteFile[
        "sftp://test.rebex.net/pub/example/readme.txt",
        Authentication -> <|
            "Username" -> "demo",
            "Password" -> "password"
            |>
    ]
```

[`Run`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html) and [`RunProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html), [`ExternalEvaluate["Shell", "Cmd"]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) or even [`RemoteRun`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoteRun.html) could be used too, if you already have a script that does the file transfer.

```
RunProcess[{"ls", "--help"}]
```

Comment: It is very disappointing that many file operations like `FileExistsQ` or `Export` do not seem to work with `RemoteFile`.